# C++ output depends on global variable initialization

Tags: c++

This Code is solution of n-queen problem.
Solving the problem I found that the output changes depends on global variable ans initialization.

If ans initialized before grid and input value is 8, the output value is 28.
If ans initialized after grid and input value is 8, the output value is 92.
I guess its memory problem but I'm not sure exactly.

Why does the output value change depending on the position of the Initialization statement?

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int ans = 0;

bool grid[14][14] = { false, };

int N;

bool isValid(int i, int cnt) {

    int x, y;

    for (x = 0; x < cnt; x++) {

        if (grid[i][x]) return false;

    }

    for (x = cnt - 1, y = i - 1; y >= 0; x--, y--) {

        if (grid[y][x]) return false;

    }

    for (x = cnt - 1, y = i + 1; y < N; x--, y++) {

        if (grid[y][x]) return false;

    }

    return true;

}

void dfs(int cnt) {

    int i;

    // basecase

    if (cnt == N) {

        ans++;

        return;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        if (!grid[i][cnt] && isValid(i, cnt)) {

        // constraint satisfied

            grid[i][cnt] = true;

            dfs(cnt + 1);

            grid[i][cnt] = false;

        }

    }

}

int main() {

    scanf("%d", &N);

    dfs(0);

    printf("%d ", ans);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So debug it. Run your program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution to find out where things first start going wrong. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I get 92 for both ways. https://ideone.com/1l1LUu https://ideone.com/2raucW What compiler are you using that gives different results? If you run it with address and undefined sanitizers the problem becomes more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/vdWv9YfGo Simple out of bounds access.

Comment: By the way, you should tag this C++. It's not C.

Comment: Another hint is that behavior as you describe is often the result array index bounds errors. This fetches data outside the array, which can be anything.  A quick way to detect if that's the problems is to add assertions at each array reference to verify the indices are in the range you expect.

Comment: Your program invokes *undefined behavior* by breaching the lower bound of one of the sub arrays. Look closely at `isValid` and consider what transpires when you enter that function on the second ascension with `i=2` and `cnt=1` . Walk the loops. It ill only take a couple iterations to see you're indexing `[-1]` on the inferior dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has **undefined behavior**. This is because at some points inside the `isValid` function you're using negative indices while accessing array `grid`'s elements. You can verify this by printing the value of `x`(which you then use in `grid[i][x]`) and notice that there are some negative values. This will result in **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said don't rely on the output of a program that has UB.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. Then and only then you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>